# Utility.dbo.ProcedureChanges

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I can not create or modify an existing stored procedure in SQL Server. I get the following error:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure CaptureStoredProcedureChanges, Line 15 [Batch Start Line 7]
>   Invalid object name 'Utility.dbo.ProcedureChanges

I am not able to find the object `Utility.dbo.ProcedureChanges` as well. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Do you have a database called Utility ? Can you access it?

Comment: Your system may assume that all db server instances have a db called utility and that a table called ProcedureChanges exists in this common "Utility" database to your environment.

Comment: Pedro Martins - I don't have a schema or database named Utility. That is why I can not look into the object to debug it.

Comment: How do you expect us to help you understand the problem if you don't share at least the code that's raising the error?